# django rss returns 404

Tags: python, django, rss, http-status-code-404

I am trying to make an RSS and ATOM feed for a blog I am working on.

But when I try to access the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/rss` of my feed, it return the error:

```
404  No post found matching the query
```

This is the content of my file **feeds.py**:

```
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
from blog.models import Post
from django.utils.feedgenerator import Atom1Feed

class RssSiteNewsFeed(Feed):
    title = "Police beat site news"
    link = "/sitenews/"
    description = "Updates on changes and additions to police beat central."

    def items(self):
        return Post.objects.all.order_by('date')[:5]

class AtomSiteNewsFeed(RssSiteNewsFeed):
    feed_type = Atom1Feed
    subtitle = RssSiteNewsFeed.description
```

Here are the relevant part of my file **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [ ...
    path('blog/rss/', RssSiteNewsFeed()),
    path('blog/atom/', AtomSiteNewsFeed()),
]
```

And finally here are the models from the file **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField (max_length = 160)
    slug =  models.SlugField(max_length = 160,unique=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    class meta :
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def get_absolute_url(self ):
        return "/blog/Category/%s" % self.slug   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField (max_length = 160, null=False)
    body = models.TextField( null=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    author =  models.CharField (max_length = 160)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 160)
    keywords = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    slug =  models.SlugField(max_length = 160,unique=True)
    img_url = models.URLField()
    short_blog_snippet=  models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    absolute_url = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self ):
        return "/blog/%s" % self.slug

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I followed the Django RSS documentation, but I don't know why it is returning the `404` error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the parentheses after `all`.

```
class RssSiteNewsFeed(Feed):
    ...
    def items(self):
        return Post.objects.all().order_by('date')[:5]
```